# Proving $(1-x)\cos x=\sin x$ has a solution in the section $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $(1-x)\cos x=\sin x$ has a solution in the section $(0,1)$

Well, this is what I did:

$g(x)=(1-x)\cos x-\sin x \\
\displaystyle\lim_{0\neq x\to0}g(x)=1 , \ \lim_{1\neq x\to1}g(x)=-1 $

So by the IVT it has to have a solution.

But I'm not really sure about these limits, is it correct ?

Comment: Your value for $g(1)$ is wrong, but it has the right sign at least. You don't need to worry so much about limits, since $g$ as you defined it is continuous on all of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good! (But note that $-\sin (1) > 0,$ but $-\sin(1) \neq -1$. (Recall, it's $\sin (\pi/2) = 1$).

You might want to add that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ (continuity is a requirement in applying the Intermediate Value Theorem), if only to satisfy any pedantic instructors.

Comment: Great. Thanks amWhy.

Comment: You're welcome, GinKin!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV +1

Answer (score 1):

the second one should be $-\sin(1)$ but that's still ok since $\sin(1) > 0$

Comment: Right. Thanks for pointing that out.